# \arraystretch both horizontally and vertically

Tags: arrays

I did an `\arraystretch` to get taller column vectors, but not the matrices are too small. How can I also stretch them horizontally so that the matrices become square-like again?

Here's the code I used:

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}
```

Comment: You have to act on `\arraycolsep`, which is a length.

Comment: so something like: `\renewcommand*{\arraycolsep}{1.8}' ?

Comment: It's a length, so `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{<length>}`

Comment: In the preamble? Why not write it down, I'll accept it as an answer?

Comment: Not without a sensible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Comment: Hmm. well I just want "whiter" matrices, i.e. with more white space inside them. But I'm afraid \arraycolsep will change other lengths too.